# Files and folders in the Desktop disappeared

Tags: 12.10, nautilus

It's quite like this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/182917/141418). But there is a little bit difference.

In my situation, all files and folders in the Desktop were disappeared. And when I right clicked on the desktop, the drop-down box didn't appear. Whatever operation I did, nothing happened.

But when I opened the `home` folder, and access the `desktop` folder from it, files and folders were there. And I could operate the files as usual.

So I wonder how to get my files and folders back to the Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @green7. His answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/191262/141418) helps me solve the problem.

First of all, I'm sure my `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` isn't changed.

Second, restart **nautilus**.

1. run the command in the terminal: `killall nautilus` or `nautilus -q`
2. press `Alt+F2`, search `nautilus` and run it.

Comment: Did not resolve the vanishing of ~/Desktop and files contained therein on my system. my user-dirs.drs is set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop. This is how I could rectify the issue.

- Go to Gnome Tweak Tool(Install it if not installed already).
- Choose    "Desktop" from the left sidebar
- Toggle "Icons on Desktop" option to "ON"

[image: Screen shot of relevant section of gnome-twek-tool]