# Desktop folder disappeared

Tags: unity, nautilus

My all folders and files on screen disappeared, I opened nautilus and realized my desktop folder disappeared. I try to fix by follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182917/desktop-folder-and-files-disappeared?newreg=d07eb50eedbc4498a1649527e50e0e97). Then in nautilus I have Desktop folder again but I can access it and on my screen all files, folders is files and folder in Home directory. I restart my computer then Desktop folder disappear again and my screen empty again!

I'm newbie in Ubuntu. Help me, please!

[this happend when I open Desktop on nautilus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpjNw.png)