# Desktop files and folders are gone after log out

Tags: 20.04, desktop-icons, gnome-tweaks

I have recently updated from 18.04 to 20.04.

I have been playing around with gnome-tweak to tweak some settings and have been rebooting or logout/login a few times. After this one time, all my desktop files and folders are gone.

I have already made sure that Desktop Icons on Tweak-extensions is on; my $HOME points to /home/username ; my `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` looks like [this one suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/191262/543795).

Any advice?

EDIT: apparently it is a problem linked to the language. My $HOME folders have their names in my native language. If I switch to English the problem pops out. Even if, after rebooting, the system asks to update the names of those paths in the selected language. For now, switching back to my native language seems to workaround the issue.