# folders disappeared from desktop and cannot run setting icon

Tags: 22.04, directory, desktop-icons

I turned on my laptop, and I realized that the files and folders have disappeared from the desktop, I can access them from the terminal but not directly on the desktop. Here is the image of my desktop. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJKoI.jpg)

I also realize that the settings button does not work. what is the problem here?

Comment: same question https://askubuntu.com/questions/182917/desktop-folder-and-files-disappeared